# Why does my state not change using immutableJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to add immutableJS to Mern.io. When I try to remove a post from my list of post then set it back in my state the state doesn't update.

```
case ActionTypes.DELETE_POST :
    const removeArray = state.get('posts')
              .filter((post) => post._id !== action.post._id)
    console.log(removeArray.length)
    state.set('posts', removeArray)
    console.log(state)
    return state;
```

In this example if I have an array of 5 I should be able to filter it out then set "posts" again with the new array. What I don't understand is that I can remove the object from the array and the removeArray will be one less than state.posts. But when I console log state it's the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

When you call `state.set(...)` it returns a new object. The original `state` is unchanged. I changed 3 lines in your snippet:

```
case ActionTypes.DELETE_POST :
    const removeArray = state.get('posts')
              .filter((post) => post._id !== action.post._id)
    console.log(removeArray.length)
    const newState = state.set('posts', removeArray) // assign to another variable
    console.log(newState) // and log here
    return newState; // and you'll probably want to return the new state
```

Comment: It also makes sense to switch to `state.update('posts', ...)`

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for updating the snippet!

Comment: @ffffranky thanks this really clears things up. I had it in my head that an immutable object saved a history every time you set a new value to a part of it.

Comment: Can someone up vote my question since the response, is helpful and I felt clarifies the problem well.